# Swift configure custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this code in uitableview controller:

```
var results: [Item] = []
...
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderCell") as! OrderTableViewCell!
    cell.item = results[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

and OrderTableViewCell.swift:

```
class OrderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    var item: Item! {
        didSet {
            self.setupCell()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var itemNo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var itemPrice: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func setupCell() {
        itemNo.text = order.document_no
        itemPrice.text = order.sum
    }

}
```

Now, i need to know is this good way to setup cell(with `didSet`), or it is better to fill this fields `itemNo` and `itemPrice` from uitableview controller?

Comment: It's a controversial topic in iOS, if you think of your `UITableViewCell` as a view then you're passing data to the view when it's aim is only visualize, but  as I said there is no silver bullet in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, this is better than adding view-dependent logic to your `UITableViewController`.

iOS apps frequently utilize the "model-view-controller" pattern, which you have here. While the details of this pattern can vary, it is generally considered a good thing to have "loosely coupled" components. Meaning, the controller shouldn't be concerned with which table cell (view) labels are showing what model information.

Additionally, encapsulating your logic like this inside of the view like this sets you up to cleanly observe updates to `Item` (your model) in the future (completely eliminating the need for additional controller interaction). You could accomplish this automatic updating via something like Key-Value Observing.

The Wikipedia page on MVC has an excellent graphic to explain how the components typically interact.

Source: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller#Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Description)

Comment: Thanks, how can i avoid that call setupCell every time cell is displayed?

Comment: I don't believe you can. Since UIKit uses the queue based approach (instead of saving all the cells in memory), it will need to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get an appropriate cell setup whenever a cell had been reused at a different indexPath. If you are experiencing performance problems with scrolling, I would check your model layer first.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it would be better done like so:

```
func setupCell(_data:DataObject) {
    // update layout depending on data
    itemNo.text = _data.document_no 
    itemPrice.text = _data.sum
}
```

Using this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// this way avoids forced unwrapping. much safer   
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderCell") as? OrderTableViewCell{
        cell.setupCell(results[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Keep in mind that because of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier the tableview is reusing the instances of the cell. Every time a cell is displayed cellForRowAtIndexPath is called over again and that cell needs to be laid out again. You don't its data to be permanent.

Comment: Thanks, how can i avoid that call setupCell every time cell is displayed?